# How to create instance of WCMUsePojo in my Prosper spec?

Tags: groovy, aem, spock, sling, sightly

I have a functioning WCMUsePojo Groovy class which is called from a sightly html component. I am trying to create an instance of my WCMUsePojo class for testing based on the content from the [Prosper](https://github.com/Citytechinc/prosper) setup method.

It's basically the same type of question as [How can I create an instance of WCMUsePojo in a servlet for a specific page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582439/how-can-i-create-an-instance-of-wcmusepojo-in-a-servlet-for-a-specific-page) But I don't see it answered and this is specifically about how to unit test methods in WCMUsePojo classes within the Prosper framework. Is there a Java or Groovy equivalent to Sightly's data-sly-use attribute?

```
def setupSpec() {
    pageBuilder.content {
        page_with_new_gridwrapper {
            'jcr:content'{
                'gridpar' {
                    'my_gridwrapper'('sling:resourceType':'my/components/my_gridwrapper') {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def "Test Page with New Grid Container"(){
    Page page = pageManager.getPage("/content/page_with_new_gridwrapper")

 // the following 2 lines return null :-( 
 // but I would prefer these to return an object with the type MyGridContainerHelper
    MyGridContainerHelper cmp = page.getContentResource().getChild("gridpar/my_gridwrapper").adaptTo(MyGridContainerHelper.class)
    Component cmp2 = WCMUtils.getComponent(page.getContentResource().getChild("gridpar/my_gridwrapper"))

    expect:
    page != null //passes
    page.getContentResource().getChild("gridpar/my_gridwrapper") != null //passes
    cmp != null // fails
    cmp2 != null // fails
    cmp.resourceType == "my/components/my_gridwrapper" // fails

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up instantiating the object and calling the init method passing in a SimpleBindings object containing the resource I was testing with. This seems to work well for my purposes.

```
MyGridContainerHelper gridContainer = new MyGridContainerHelper();
SimpleBindings bindings = new SimpleBindings()
bindings.put("resource", page.getContentResource().getChild("gridpar/my_gridwrapper"))
gridContainer.init(bindings)
```

Answer (score 1):

To adapt an instance of `MyGridContainerHelper` from a resource object, you can implement your helper class using [Sling Models](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html) rather than extending `WCMUsePojo`.  Prosper supports registration of `@org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model`-annotated classes by using the following syntax in the `setupSpec` block of your specification:

```
slingContext.addModelsForPackage("helper.class.package.name")
```

This eliminates the need to manually construct a `Bindings` object and initialize the POJO; the Sling model factory does all the work for you.  Since Sightly's "use" attribute supports any class that is adaptable from a `Resource` or `SlingHttpServletRequest`, no additional changes are required for your existing Sightly template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The project has a lot of WCMUse classes and I'm not quite ready to convert them all to Sling Models. Going forward, I will definitely consider this solution. Since the original question is about adding tests for the existing WCMUse classes, I'll probably accept my SimpleBindings answer.